# Alloy - Declare 1 or 2 variables

Tags: variables, expression, alloy

I would like to be able to declare one or two variables of the same type from a set called `group`. I know that `one` and `lone` can be used to declare one or zero/one variables respectively. My attempt so far is :

```
    one x : group, lone y : from | {...}
```

However, this doesn't appear to work. My aim is to have either one or two variables that I can then use in the following expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be confusion here. 
If you write `one x:group| expr` this means that there should be exactly one x in group so that the expression `expr` holds.

Knowing this, if you want to express that kind of constraint, you could write something like this :
*e.g. assuming there is a field named `size` describing a relation from `group` to `Int`,
Expressing that at least one and at most two groups have a size of 5 can be done as follows*

```
one x,y : group | (x + y).size=5
```

In this example, `x+y` will yield one or two group elements depending on whether `x=y` or not.

Comment: What do you mean by a size of five?

Comment: it's an example of expression, i invented it. give me more context and I'll adapt this example to your need

Comment: I understand now, I already have my expression but thank you very much.